# Shading area in graphics

Tags: graphics

I want to shade the area between the formula

```
eqn=(a (Sqrt[a] (-40 + 37 a + 10 a^2 - 3 a^3) + (-1 + a)^2 (32 + 
  a) ArcTanh[Sqrt[a]]))/(2 (-Sqrt[a] (1 + a) + (-1 + a)^2 ArcTanh[
 Sqrt[a]]))
```

and `-3/2`.

To be clearer: `-3/2 < region to be shaded < eqn`

I tried with:

```
Show[{{Plot[{eqn, -3/2}, {a, -2, 1.5}]}, 
  Plot[{eqn, -3/2}, {a, -1.2, 1}, 
   Filling -> {1 -> {-3/2, Automatic}}]}, PlotRange -> {-2, 4}]
```

but I don't get what I want: it shades also

```
eqn < region < -3/2
```

Any ideas?

I am sorry but I don't understand how to link a figures, I hope I explained myself...

Oh, I am using Mathematica 8.

Comment: Check the documentation for `Filling` - you can specify different filling styles for above and below the curve.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use

```
Plot[{eqn, -3/2}, {a, -1.2, 1}, Filling -> {1 -> {-3/2, {White, LightBlue}}}, PlotRange -> {-2, 4}]
```

to fill the area between the two curves: >-3/2=LightBlue and <-3/2=White

[image]

Comment: It worked. thank you